# php code logic by version

Tags: php, version, try-catch-finally

I want a solution something like: Imagine I have `try catch` block, it works in any php 5.?.? version but with `finally` block not in any. my code must be like this:

```
try {

    // some logic

} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // some logic
} finally {
    // other logic
}
```

but, how can I make so that finally block worked only if php version supports it else ignore? For example:

```
try {
    // some logic
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    // some logic
}
#if version=5.?.?
finally {
    // other logic
}
#endif
```

Is there any solution?

Comment: If you can make without finally block -- why use finally block?

Comment: if I will throw exception in catch block there always will be executed code inside `finally` nevertheless of `throw`

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24427168/4577762) could be related: _You could include different scripts based on version_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get php version by [phpversion method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpversion.php). The only option you have is to write an if statement to check it; if it supports write the whole try-catch-finally block. If it does not, write only try-catch. You can use inline functions to prevent duplicate code. I have no idea why somebody needs this, but for example;

```
function fncTry(){...}
function fncCatch($exception){...}
function fncFinally(){...}

if($phpVersion == '5.5'){
   try { fncTry(); }
   catch(Exception $ex) { fncCatch($ex); }
   finally { fncFinally(); }
}else{
   try { fncTry(); }
   catch(Exception $ex) { fncCatch($ex); }

   fncFinally();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

phpversion() will return a string of the php version. (Example: "5.6.14")

You can use that to set up your conditional statement.

Comment: Question is not about checking php version

Comment: Since "finally" is only supported in php 5.5 or later, yes, technically, it is a question of which version of php is being used.

Answer (score 0):

i am sorry i'm confused :)

[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17208838/php-5-5-and-try-finally)

and you could check about phpversion before you make the try catch

if (php version == 5.5 or greater)

you make it with finally

else you make it without finally

Comment: Question is not about checking php version.

Comment: sorry i didn't recognize

Comment: And what function should be checked - `finally`? `finally` is not a function.

Comment: check the link i've add